# IOS Coreplot scatterplot animation drawing

Tags: ios, core-plot, cabasicanimation

I need to animate in ios a scatterplot to make it as the line was drawing. There is a similar effect in this website http://www.highcharts.com .I tried unsuccessfully with basic animation but impossible to make this effect.
Does anyone has any idea on how to do it ?

Comment: I too need that effect using core plot animation, Please any one give solution to get that type of effect as in  http://www.highcharts.com.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I've found CorePlot's animation capabilities in this area limiting.

However I have had success achieving the same effect by animating expanding the expansion of a regular UIView which encapsulates the graph.

I don't have my code in front of my at the moment by here is a diagram to highlight how I did it:

[image]

The key thing here is you start the initial Animation with a UIView which contains the Graph and who's frame is a smaller width than the graph. Then you animate the frame width to be the full graph size.

When this animates it progressively reveals your graph in a smooth animation.